# jquery focus problem

Tags: jquery, css, focus, hover, addition

Hello all im trying to add a class when i focus on a small image but it dont add the class, what im doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/6rnU4/

Comment: i have edit the css to .hover so its not #hover, but it still not work -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with the `:hover` pseudo-class?

```
#small-image img:hover {
  border: 5px solid #333;
}
```

Or

```
#small-image:hover {
    border: 5px solid #333;
}
```

*(depending your intent)*

Also, `#hover` implies this is a page element with the ID "hover", not an element with the class hover applied. I think you're looking for `.hover`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in the latest jquery you need $(document).ready().

Secondly you were overcoding the hide all but first.

And you had missed out the img from your identifier on the add class block, see:

Addition:: Brad Christie is right, if you just want to add a border you should use :hover in your css, if this is just for testing then http://jsfiddle.net/6rnU4/10/ this now works.

further to the changes above, In your css the .hover was being overridden by #small-image img because it has greater specificity.

Comment: i thought  $(document() {}) was okay with the new jquery versions, do you know what im still doing wrong cause it still dont work to show the border on hover :S

Comment: /@Sjmon: `$(function(){ ... });` is synonymous with `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.